# How to count zero results in COUNT aggregate across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, database, db2, aggregate-functions

I have 3 example tables:
1. Person

```
PID         PNAME                         
----------- ------------------------------
111111111.  James Brock
222222222.  Dean Sampson
333333333.  Adam Klein
444444444.  Sam Toggle
```

2. Company

   CID         CNAME

   ---

   123456789. Company A
   123456790. Company B
   123456791. Company C
   123456792. Company D
3. Working

   PID         CNAME

   ---

   111111111. Company B
   111111112. Company A
   111111113. Company A
   111111114. Company C

I want to show the # of employees at each company, including those that don't have any employees (ie: 0 of them)

So I have this so far:

```
SELECT CNAME, COUNT(*) as EMPLOYEES
    FROM PERSON P, WORKING W, COMPANY C
    WHERE P.PID = W.PID
        AND W.CNAME = C.CNAME
    GROUP BY CNAME;
```

Which returns:

```
CNAME       EMPLOYEES                         
----------- ------------------------------
Company A   2
Company B   1
Company C   1
```

*Notice that Company D is missing*

I want this:

```
CNAME       EMPLOYEES                         
----------- ------------------------------
Company A   2
Company B   1
Company C   1
Company D   0
```

Is there an approach I can take to get the result I want? All other examples I found online only use 2 tables to match.

Comment: PID's in working do not correspond to those in person. Working table would not contain cname but cid in stead.  Only then would you need to join three tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Then, the `LEFT JOIN` would be obvious.

```
SELECT C.CNAME, COUNT(W.PID) as EMPLOYEES
FROM COMPANY C LEFT JOIN
     WORKING W
     ON W.CNAME = C.CNAME
GROUP BY C.CNAME;
```

Note that the `JOIN` to `PERSON` is unnecessary.  You are only counting the people, not looking up their names.